# Limiting the number of checkboxes selected by user in PHP

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

I created the follwing `table` which gives the user option to uses check boxes to ehter the selection. I limited the number of selection to four, but its selecting more than 4 choices.

HTML:

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th width="37%" height="19" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <strong>Biological</strong>
        </th>
        <th width="37%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <strong>Psychological</strong>
        </th>
        <th width="37%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <strong>Social</strong>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Antidepressant" id="Antidepressant" value="Antidepressant" onclick="chkcontrol(1)" />
            <label for="Antidepressant"></label>Antidepressant</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Antipsychotic oral" id="Antipsychotic oral" value="Antipsychotic oral" onclick="chkcontrol(2)" />
            <label for="Antipsychotic oral"></label>Antipsychotic oral</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Antipsychotic_depot" id="Antipsychotic depot" value="Antipsychotic depot" onclick="chkcontrol(3)" />
            <label for="Antipsychotic depot"></label>Antipsychotic depot</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Bblocker" id="B-blocker" value="B-blocker" onclick="chkcontrol(4)" />
            <label for="B-blocker"></label>B-blocker</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Benzodiazepine" id="Benzodiazepine" value="Benzodiazepine" onclick="chkcontrol(5)" />
            <label for="Benzodiazepine"></label>Benzodiazepine</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Mood_stabiliser" id="Mood stabiliser" value="Mood stabiliser" onclick="chkcontrol(6)" />
            <label for="Mood stabiliser"></label>Mood stabiliser</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="ECT" id="ECT" value="ECT" onclick="chkcontrol(7)" />
            <label for="ECT"></label>ECT</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Otherbio" id="Other" value="Other" />
            <label for="Other"></label>Other</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The script used to chec the number of selection:

```
function chkcontrol(j) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++) {
        if (document.form1.ckb[i].checked) {
            total = total + 1;
        }
        if (total > 4) {
            alert("Please Select only three")
            document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: but the script is not working and allowing the user to select more than 4 choices

Comment: What has PHP got to do with this? Its only javascript..

Comment: for starters, those are radio buttons not checkboxes.

Comment: You don't have "form1.ckb" on your HTML so the JS code does nothing

Comment: and also IDs in HTML cannot have spaces e.g. `id="Antipsychotic depot"`

Comment: What you should use there is checkboxes, not radio buttons.

Comment: There are lots of problems in your code. First, [it should be `<input>` instead of `<input />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input). Second, `id="Mood stabiliser"` is not correct because [no space is allowed in `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes). Third, `<label>`s are [not used like that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label). Here's a good HTML reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML

Comment: @Derek: `<input />` with a `/` is required for xhtml, and does no harm in (non-x)html.

Comment: @nnnnnn - You're right, and it is ok in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few minor corrections:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function chkcontrol(j) {
    var total=0;
    for(var i=0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++){
        if(document.form1.ckb[i].checked){
            total =total +1;
        }
        if(total > 4){
            alert("Please Select only four!")
            document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false ;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <form action="" id="form1" name="form1">
            <tr>
              <th width="37%" height="19" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Biological</strong></th>
              <th width="37%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong> Psychological</strong></th>
              <th width="37%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong> Social</strong></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="radio" name="Antidepressant" id="ckb" value="Antidepressant" onclick="chkcontrol(0);" />
                <label for="Antidepressant"></label>Antidepressant</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="radio" name="Antipsychotic oral" id="ckb" value="Antipsychotic oral" onclick="chkcontrol(1);" />
                <label for="Antipsychotic oral"></label>Antipsychotic oral</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="radio" name="Antipsychotic_depot" id="ckb" value="Antipsychotic depot" onclick="chkcontrol(2);" />
                <label for="Antipsychotic depot"></label>Antipsychotic depot</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="radio" name="Bblocker" id="ckb" value="B-blocker"  onclick="chkcontrol(3);"/>
                <label for="B-blocker"></label>B-blocker</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="radio" name="Benzodiazepine" id="ckb" value="Benzodiazepine"  onclick="chkcontrol(4);"/>
                <label for="Benzodiazepine"></label>Benzodiazepine</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="radio" name="Mood_stabiliser" id="ckb" value="Mood stabiliser"  onclick="chkcontrol(5);"/>
                <label for="Mood stabiliser"></label>Mood stabiliser</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="radio" name="ECT" id="ckb" value="ECT"  onclick="chkcontrol(6);"/>
                <label for="ECT"></label>ECT</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="radio" name="Otherbio" id="ckb" value="Other"  onclick="chkcontrol(7);"/>
                <label for="Other"></label>
                Other</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Still, it doesn't make sense as the form is not submitting its content anywhere, but it's a good POC.

Comment: multiple `id="ckb"` is not correct. `<label>` also refers to the `element_id` and not the name.

Comment: @Tina - There are *much* more errors in your code. See my comment above.

Comment: i meant the label should refer to the `element_id` not the name.

Comment: @tradyblix I didn't intent to start fixing all the errors, just to demonstrate how to make it work. There are other things that I would change such as: assigning the "onclick" method on the head instead of the body etc.

Comment: i understand that i just want to point out that what's `corrected` is not correct. the OP's original `id` and `<label>` relationship is right (except the space in id) than what you posted. yes it may be working now but it doesn't improve the code.

Comment: The label elements are pointless here anyway since they're empty: what should be the label content is currently _after_ the closing `</label>` tags.